# Unsure what values to use to initialize my Neural Net

Tags: java, neural-network

```
    /**
 * Loads data from a file for training/test purposes.
 * Separator is comma + possible whitespace or just whitespace.
 * @param filename - the name of a text file that contains
 *                   a list of patterns/targets.
 *                   For each pattern, the list of inputs
 *                   for that pattern followed by the list
 *                   of outputs. 
 * @param inputs   - 2D array into which input patterns are
 *                   place. First index is pattern number, 
 *                   second is input index. The length of
 *                   this array must not be longer than the 
 *                   number of patterns in the file.
 * @param targets  - array into which targets are placed. 
 */
public static void loadData(String filename, 
        double[][] inputs,
        double[][] targets) {
    if (inputs.length != targets.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Different number of patterns inputs/targets.");

    int numPatterns = inputs.length;
    int inputLength = inputs[0].length;
    int targetLength = targets[0].length;

    File inFile = new File(filename);
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile);
        sc.useDelimiter("[,\\s]\\s*");
        for(int k = 0; k < numPatterns; k++){
            for(int i = 0; i< inputLength; i++)
                inputs[k][i]= sc.nextDouble();
            //System.out.println(sc.next());
            for(int j = 0; j < targetLength; j++)
                targets[k][j] = sc.nextDouble();
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(1);

    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that the javadoc isnt clear to me.  I dont know what "pattern number" is, and I dont know what "input index" is.

The file I am reading in as a list of CSV's in the form

47,100, 27, 81, 57, 37, 26, 0, 0, 23, 56, 53, 100, 90, 40, 98, 8.  The first 16 digits are the x,y coordinates on a plane, and the 17th digit is the number they are supposed to draw.

What would I put in the "inputs" field, and what would I put into the "targets" field?

Answer (score 0):

Those are pretty standard inputs for a neural network.

Think of the neural network as two sets of matrices: activations, and weights. The inputs are a 2D array; one dimension is equal in size to the first layer of the activations, the other is how many training items you have. The target is the target space; it has to be equal in dimension to the output layer's size (on the activations) and again the number of training samples you have.

It would help to have some context for what you're using the network for, and always post the error your getting. My suspicion is that somewhere along the line your getting a matrix multiplication error for mismatching dimensions because you didn't align things as described above.

Note that this description doesn't hold for all networks, just mlps and their derivatives (multi-layer percptrons - basic feed-forward back-propagate machines).

Here's the best image I could find (it isn't great - I don't like how the weights are shown as lines when they're probably a matrix too) - see how the activations on the front of the network have to align with the input? Again, it isn't painfully obvious from the diagrams, which are generally designed to be more neurological looking than mathematical, but I hope this helps clear things up.

[image]

**EDIT** For clarity after your comment

A "dimension" is the number of items in a row or column in a matrix. It has nothing to do with any of the values in the matrix - you pick those at your leisure. And a matrix is just a nested array. So: the number of rows in the input should be the number of activations on the starting layer on your network; the number of columns in the input should be the number of samples you have (or reversed, depending on your axes).

The hidden layer can be whatever you want. Hint: take it out for now, put it in only when you're tuning.

I highly recommend doing a lot more reading before starting to use these - they're very cool, but it only get's tougher :) Work through the source code, see how things work, do tutorials, delve into the literature, etc.

Comment: So on the input dimension, the first value in the matrix would be the number of neurons in the first hidden layer, and the second value would be the number of sets of 17 numbers I have?

And for the target, it would be the number of values im returning in the output layer, and the number of sets of 17 numbers I have?